# DocBook XSL chunking

Tags: xslt, docbook, chunking

Can anyone point me to the part of this file that controls chunking?

http://docbook4j.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/docbook4j/src/main/resources/xsl/docbook/webhelp/xsl/webhelp-common.xsl

I can't relate what I find in this doc to the code I see in that file:

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Chunking.html

I want to modify the XSL so that it chunks at <?confluence type="page" ?> instead of <section xml:id= ...>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main XSL stylesheet DocBook Webhelp uses is [webhelp.xsl](http://docbook4j.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/docbook4j/src/main/resources/xsl/docbook/webhelp/xsl/webhelp.xsl). This includes the webhelp-common.xsl, and imports the [xhtml chunk.xsl](http://docbook4j.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/docbook4j/src/main/resources/xsl/docbook/xhtml/chunk.xsl). The chunking code is included in the chunk.xsl and the stylesheets it imports especially the chunk-common.xsl.

Comment: So the lines in the xhtml chunk-common.xls that refer to xml:id are the ones I'd want to modify?

Comment: May be this line -  `<xsl:for-each select="d:section|d:sect1|d:refsection|d:refsect1">`

Comment: Thanks, that should get me started.